# Python 3.1 - Grid simulation

Tags: python

I'm hoping to get some tips on what direction I should take, to complete the following;

I need to take a 1D list of integers, and convert it into a grid; where the integers are randomly placed (multi-dimensional array?). I then need a function, where when I select and then modify one of the grid elements, all surrounding elements will be affected also.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Your question is really vague. AFAIU, you need to convert a 1 dimensional list to 2-dimensional list, right? (are you trying to write game of life?)

Comment: Yes it will be 2-dimensional. No not really, as I understand the game of life, continues? What I wan't is to modify a single element in the grid, and have the neighboring elements change also. Then I will sample the now modified grid. I will however, look for python implementations of this game of life, as it might help.

Comment: If you found one of these answers helpful, why not accept one? (I don't care whose.)

Comment: If a certain answer solved your problem, please accept it(click the outline of a checkmark next to the answer).  You will gain reputation.  Also, if an answer is helpful at all(whether it solves your problem or not) please upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's a quick one:

```
1d_list = [45, 18, 77, 24, 47, 88, 61, 96, 46, 97, 16, 65, 39, 56, 14, 48, 87, 44, 91, 22, 21, 38, 59, 95, 75, 80, 20, 51, 66, 62, 50, 82, 60, 57, 10, 23, 6, 8, 28, 83, 71, 76, 36, 32, 90, 29, 40, 37] // I didn't write this ;)

2d_list = []

for y in range(6):
  holder = []

  for x in range(8):
    holder.append(x)

  2d_list.append(y)
  2d_list[y].append(holder)
```

Now, you can just use `2d_list` like you would a normal coordinate system:

```
print 2d_list[0][4] // Output: 47
```

Good luck. If it's going to be big, you'll need to use [Python Arrays](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html), as Lists and Dictionaries just won't cut it any more due to speed issues (I might be mixed up. There *should* be a C array implementation in Python, right?).

Comment: Is it much faster than using a C array? I found numpy to be just as sluggish as Python's internal list structures when dealing with this stuff (well, my tests weren't extensive at all).